# How to style flat button to ImageButton?

Tags: android, android-imagebutton

I want to put the button style in `imagebutton`.

[image: ImagenButton Default]

```
style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionButton"
```

[image: Flat ImagenButton]

How to put the style of buttons 3, 6, 9?

Comment: post your xml code

Comment: they are normal components, on the theme apptheme default. Theme parent AppCompat Light

Comment: what you actually want? all buttons same as first image right?

Comment: all the same as the buttons = 3,6,9

Comment: the shadow comes from the other buttons. Imagenbutton seems to be under the buttons. It does not have the effect of touching the button either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
                        <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/btndel"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="60dp"
                        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_backspace_black_24dp"
                        android:background = "@color/white"
                        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"/>
```

@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored it's the solution.-